# Slide in Table Sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using currently this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleSibling(sibling)
    {
          sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
          while(!/tr/i.test(sibling.nodeName))
          {
              sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
          }
          sibling.style.display = sibling.style.display == 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }
</script>
```

to toggle sibling for my table. but it appears instantly after clicking on it. I am wondering if there is any way to make it Slide in instead just showing up.

Demo: jsfiddle.net/82XN3/1
Thanks.

Comment: Plz post a demo on http://jsfiddle.net how it behaves now

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/82XN3/1/ Click on the text and it opens the subtext, but I want it to be slided in not just popping instantly. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$(sibling).slideToggle();
```

instead of

```
sibling.style.display = sibling.style.display == 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
```

But it kinda sucks on table rows, when it reaches minimum height it hides instantly

**Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/82XN3/2/**

Instead of table I suggest using DIVs, for example

**HTML**

```
<div class="norm">
    123
</div>
<div class="norm sun">
    123
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.norm {border: solid 1px red; width:200px;height:50px}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.sun').hide()

$('.norm').click(function() {

    $(this).next().slideToggle()

})
```

It works much smoother

**Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/82XN3/3/**

and you can adjust code to your needs. Note it's much easier to traverse the DOM using jQuery then standard JS implementation

Comment: OK. Thanks I will consider using divs instead table

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:

Instead of directly editing the display, you can use `$(sibling).slideToggle();`

http://jsfiddle.net/5yu45/

Looks like the row height can't be less than the content height, so it 'pops' to the content height and slides the rest of the way. You may be able to wrap the inner element in a div, and set the div's height and overflow properties to get around this.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but yes using rows is bad choise